# Tensorflow: error converging towards constant value

Tags: tensorflow

I am struggling with a simple example in Tensorflow where I try to classify 4 vectors. Basically, a vector of the type [n, n, n, n] should be assigned to category n.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

data=np.array([[1,1,1,1],
               [2,2,2,2],
               [3,3,3,3],
               [4,4,4,4]])
labels=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(4, 1))),
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=1000)

print(model.predict(np.array([[1,1,1,1]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[2,2,2,2]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[3,3,3,3]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[4,4,4,4]])))
```

Unfortunately, the error converges to a constant value, 1.25, and the model always predicts the same thing: [[[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1,5]].

The other thing that surprises me is the dimension of the prediction. I expected that, if I gave it a single vector as an argument, it would give me a single label instead of a vector of 4 identical values.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your last layer. You are doing multi-class classification, but you have one output neuron. You have to have 4 neurons since you are trying to predict 4 classes, so a neuron for each class.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

data=np.array([[1,1,1,1],
               [2,2,2,2],
               [3,3,3,3],
               [4,4,4,4]])
labels=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,))),
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=1000)

print(model.predict(np.array([[1,1,1,1]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[2,2,2,2]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[3,3,3,3]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[4,4,4,4]])))
```

Regarding the output shape of the prediction, you can use the argmax function to get the index of the predicted class. Here is an example:

```
predictions = model.predict(np.array([[1,1,1,1]]))
predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions[0])
print(predicted_class)
```

Edit: Didn't spot this before but your network is also just mapping the input neurons to the output neurons, its not going to be able to learn a correct mapping, it will always underfit. You need to add more layers in between:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

data=np.array([[1,1,1,1],
               [2,2,2,2],
               [3,3,3,3],
               [4,4,4,4]])
labels=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, labels, epochs=1000)

print(model.predict(np.array([[1,1,1,1]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[2,2,2,2]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[3,3,3,3]])))
print(model.predict(np.array([[4,4,4,4]])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, I am getting a similar behaviour. The error converges towards 0.25. The predictions are different for various vectors but they are still not correct. Thanks!

Comment: I read your comment about the neural network being too simple only after having written my reply. In fact, this comes from a much more complicated example featuring a large CNN where I noticed the same behaviour as now. The error was converging towards a constant value and the predicted labels were wrong and sometimes the same. This occurred for a single output as well as for as many outputs as categories. I still have the same problem after having added a layer. The error is non-zero and the predictions are wrong.

Comment: In fact, it's so simple that it should work with a single neuron but, even in that case, it fails in the same way.

Comment: @zaphod not sure why its not working for you, I just ran in in colab, and after 1000 epochs I get the correct predictions and 100% accuracy. are you predicting with argmax method mentioned above?

Comment: Thank you very much for having tried. You had also changed the loss function to "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" and, when I made that change too, it worked. Thank you very much! But, now, I am wondering why it doesn't work with MeanSquareError.

Comment: @zaphod sparse_categorical_crossentropy is used when your labels are in number form, i.e.  what you had: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. What you were doing before wasn't solving a classification problem, you were trying to solve a regression problem by trying to get the output to match the correct label. Instead, by using four output neurons, one for each class, you get to tell the network that you want the correct neuron to fire for the correct label. Your first approach is problematic for many reasons, which are too many to explain in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I had made a regression problem out of it. I knew it was not right but, as a first shot (I am new to Tensorflow), I had thought that the network could be trained to give me the output I wanted. This was part of debugging a more complicated problem and it was one of the issues I wanted to address. Thank you for your help!